# Running Virtualbox as a Transparent Bridge

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

I am setting up Untangle in a Sun VirtualBox VM.  I plan on using this machine as a transparent bridge to filter and monitor traffic on my network. I'm not sure how to configure the network adapters for the virtual machine under the Virtualbox's "Devices" menu so that it will function as a transparent bridge. I guess what I'm asking is, should both adapter 1 & 2 be set as Bridged adapters or what?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should create two virtual adapters in bridged mode and bind them to your two physical network cards on the host. Then set up Untangle as a transparent bridge between the two interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the response b0fh however I opted to go with VMWare as the Virtual host as opposed to Virtualbox since there seems to be a lot more documentation on the web on how to configure things.  I now have Untangle up and running in a VMWare machine as a transparent bridge and its working great. I will close the question and thanks again.